# MongoDB Group By query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

How I can implement on MongoDb this SQL Query

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Tracks
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Tracks WHERE UserID IN ([UserIDs...]) GROUP BY UserID)
```

Tracks structure:

```
Tracks[{_id, userId, {lat, lon},  dateCreate, ...}, ...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use the aggregation framework for this:

```
db.Tracks.aggregate( [
    { $match: { 'UserID': { $in: [ UserIDs ] } } },
    { $group: { _id: '$UserID', max: { $max: '$_id' } },
    { $sort: { $max: -1 } },
    { $limit: 100 }
] );
```

First we match against the wanted UserIDs, then we group depending on UserID and also put the maximum `_id` value in the new `max` field. Then we sort by `max` descendently to get the highest `max` numbers first and then we limit by the top 100.

Comment: ReadStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBsonType is Document, not when CurrentBsonType is Array.

Comment: Your "Track" doesn't even have a UserID, how can I guess that sort of thing?! And I've no idea what "ReadStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBsonType is Document, not when CurrentBsonType is Array" even means. I gave you the MongoDB query that matches your SQL, which is what you were asking for.